# Problem about opening webcam(logitech C920)

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this website http://answers.ros.org/question/197651/how-to-install-a-driver-like-usb_cam/?answer=230326#post-id-230326   ,try to open my webcam. There are some errors about comand

```
$ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node
```

It shows error message like the following.

```
[ INFO] [1459206531.320684602]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1459206531.321520602]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/udooer/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1459206531.322092602]: Unable to open camera calibration file 
[/home/udooer/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1459206531.322306602]: Camera calibration file /home/udooer/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1459206531.322585935]: Starting 'head_camera' (/dev/video0) at 640x480 via mmap (yuyv) at 30 FPS
[ERROR] [1459206531.327861602]: Cannot open '/dev/video0': 11, Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I have tried to open my camera (logitech C920) with guvcview successfully. However,it still can't work on ROS .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230377/problem-about-opening-webcam(logitech-c920)/) by [Joy.Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26415/joy.lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25953/niranjan/) on 2016-03-29**:
what is the error message...

**Comment by [Joy.Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26415/joy.lin/) on 2016-03-29**:
Sorry , error message was cut.
[ INFO] [1459206531.320684602]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1459206531.321520602]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/udooer/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml
[ INFO] [1459206531.322092602]: Unable to open camera

**Comment by [Niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25953/niranjan/) on 2016-03-31**:
use this comment to check the camera connected port `ls /dev/video*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usb_cam_node is trying to open the camera in **/dev/video0**. Usually, video0 is the primary camera. You may change it into **/dev/video1** in order to access the usb camera.

---

Originally posted by [AnandGeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/23126/anandgeorge/) with karma: 56 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy.Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26415/joy.lin/) on 2016-03-29**:
Thank for your answer. I tried to exchange /dev/video0. with /dev/video1 , but it still showed me  [ERROR] [1459206531.327861602]: Cannot open '/dev/video1': 11, Resource temporarily unavailable
There are the other messages it showed me. I add them above.